# Positive-Eigenvalue Jacobian $\Rightarrow$ Invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ has Jacobian $Jf : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathsf{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with positive eigenvalues everywhere. Is $f$ (globally) injective (invertible on its range)?

If $Jf$ was also guaranteed to be symmetric, this would be true by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124139/173871). We also know $f$ is locally invertible by the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Take $f=\arctan$. Then $f' >0$ but it is not surjective.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess I should specify invertible on it's range i.e. injective

Comment: There was nothing about the linked proof which required symmetry. All you need is that $\langle (Jf)x,x\rangle >0$ for all $x\neq 0$, which follows since the smallest eigenvalue is $\min_{\|x\|=1} \langle (Jf)x,x\rangle$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Forgive me if I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure that only works for self-adjoint $Jf$. $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is a counterexamples with $x=[1,1]^*$.

Comment: You are right, apologies for my hasty comment.

Comment: A Jacobian with positive _real part_ of the eigenvalues is not enough: consider $f(x,y)=(x+2y,y-x^2)$.